# Windows USB boot disk for Dell XPS 15 (9570)

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, dell-xps

I am trying to create a USB boot disk for Dell XPS 15 (9570). I tried unetbootin and etcher (on Mac), I also tried copying files from ISO directly onto the USB (on Linux). I am never able to get it to work.

I was finally able to even boot it with unetbootin and USB formatted to FAT32. However, one of the files is corrupted (I believe because it's larger than file size limit). I tried make an image using ExFat, but then the USB doesn't appear in the boot menu (there is a legacy USB boot option - this doesn't start, there is just a blinking cursor).

I also tried bootcamp tool, but this one didn't work for me either (no option to choose USB as the destination for the image).

Is there a way for me to create a working USB with windows 0 image?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Linux image, I've found [Rufus](http://rufus.ie/en_US/) to be reliable. For example, to make a Ubuntu Live USB, [download the ISO image](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and use Rufus to put it on the USB flash drive.

Use a flash USB drive of 8 to 32 GB, formatted FAT32, for best chance of success, because exFAT is proprietary, and may require additional packages (*fuse*) for Linux to read.

Be sure the BIOS/UEFI settings are correct; likely UEFI mode and Secure Boot *on*, Fast Boot *off* (Fast Boot retains Windows startup info on disk, preventing booting to other OS).

As for creating a Windows installation media, if the Dell had Windows on it, then you should be able to use a USB made using the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d). There are, perhaps, other ways to do this, though they some have issues.